Clicking Hyperlink Masquerading as Button with Puppeteer
I'm new to Puppeteer. I'm having problems clicking a certain button, I suspect because it's a hyperlink masquerading as button. I'm interested in the element shown on line 3.
1 <div class="pull-right">
2  <button class="btn internal-close">Cancel</button>
3  <a href="#" id="export_people_action" class="btn btn-primary excel">Download</a>
4  <div id="directory_export_people_actions_container" class="btn-group dropup hide pull-right" style="margin-left: 7px;">
5    <a href="#" id="directory_save_and_replace_existing_template" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>
6    <button class="btn btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
7      <i class="icon-caret-down" style="margin-left: -2px; margin-right: -3px;">
8      </i>
9    </button>
10    <ul class="dropdown-menu align_left">
11      <li class="">
12        <a href="#" class="trigger_export_people_action">Download Without Updating</a>
13      </li>
14      <li class="">
15        <a href="#" id="directory_save_as_new_template">Save as New Template</a>
16      </li>
17    </ul>
18    <input type="hidden" id="email_later_delay" value="">
19    <input type="hidden" id="temp_download" value="false">
20    <input type="hidden" id="unedited_template" value="">
21  </div>
22 </div>

Here are some things that I've tried:
(1) At first, I thought it worked like any other button, so I used the id.
await page.click('#export_people_action');

Returns an error "Error: No element found for selector: #export_people_action".
(2) Then I started looking more closely, and realized that it's a link. I tried XPath.
const downloadButton = await page.waitForSelector('::-p-xpath(//*[@class="btn btn-primary excel"])');
await downloadButton.click();

Returns an error "TimeoutError: Waiting for selector [[[{"name":"xpath","value":"//*[@class=\"btn btn-primary excel\"]"}]]] failed: Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded".
I've tried it a few different ways since then, but along those two lines, with no success. I confess I'm at a bit of a loss.

Please share a [mcve] with the actual site being automated.  Based on the HTML you've shown, await page.click('#export_people_action'); should work fine, so if that doesn't work, then there's some other behavior on the page that is important for reproducing the problem. For example, the element might be in an iframe, might not be actionable (is underneath an overlay, for example), may be in a shadow root, or it may be that the server is blocking you or delivering a different page than you're seeing as a human in the browser. Or one of many other possibilities.

It was an iframe! You're fantastic. @ggorlen. I've pasted the new code in an edit.

Success! @ggorlen correctly identified that the button was in an iframe.
      await page.waitForSelector('iframe');
      const elementHandle = await page.$(
        'iframe[src="/zephyr/export"]'
      )
      const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
      await delay(100);
      await frame.click('#export_people_action')

